# Contrasting color palette in python

Tags: python, plot, colormap

Can someone tell me how I can generate a contrasting color palette in python. I need a set of colors that give a good contrast (distinguished easily) on a plot in color and B/W. It is important to have contrast in B/W if not completely in color.

Thanks

edit: I am currently using matplotlib, python 2.7. I use the default pyplot which generates colors which can sometimes be very close specially when converted to B/W. I would like to generate colors that can be distinguished easily even in shades of grey. I am not using any additional libraries.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, per se - you could just play around with RGB values in a colour wheel online or something to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp I am using the color palette in python plots. Playing around with a wheel online is just a backup solution.

Comment: Well, we don't really know what you want when you say "contrasting colors", that's not really objective enough. Can you be more specific as to what platform and what libraries you're using right now, inside the question itself?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Edited the question as suggested. I am just using what is provided by default.

Comment: I think this is a great question. It is highly relevant for anyone who has created scientific figures in which they need to represent categorical data. Sequential colormaps are not what you really want for this. The OP wants *contrasting* colormaps. This could be a fun and interesting programming problem, but for an out-of-the-box solution, I recommend https://github.com/taketwo/glasbey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plotting what you describe as a color palette is referred to as **colormap**.

There are several sequential colormaps that fulfill the desired properties.
I suggest you have a look at the colormaps provided by matplotlib ([examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)) for starters, but I agree it is hard to find ones with perceptually linear luminance that really add something to just B/W.

If you like to devulge further into the topic of finding the 'perfect' colormap, I suggest you have a look at the works by [Kenneth Moreland](http://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-advice/) and [Peter Kovesi](http://peterkovesi.com/projects/colourmaps/). They both provide links for using/generating their colormaps in python.

I find the colormaps by Kenneth Moreland to be especially intriguing for perceptually linear luminance or linearly increasing brightness.